# Why Azure App Service doesn;t use launchSettings.json config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need some help.

I deployed Asp Net Core app on Azure App Service(Windows). It's not use my standart configurations in launchSettings.json [image]

But uses random port per starting.
For example :

[INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:4340"

[INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:8105"

[INF] Now listening on: "http://127.0.0.1:13605"

When I running it in my own computer all routes and ports work correct. Why this situation appear with Azure App Service deploy ?

Comment: i am not a network expert but i do deploy a lot of apps. during local development, we set the port because, we have one computer which could be running many services on the same host. but, in case of an app service, it just does one thing. also, this seems more like an internal port situation. based on your app configuration, the correct ports are made available, right? also, is this affecting your actual app functionality? i am simply curious to know how is this affecting your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `launchSettings.json` is **exclusively** for Visual Studio.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> The environment for local machine development can be set in the Properties\launchSettings.json file of the project. Environment values set in launchSettings.json override values set in the system environment.
>
> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - contains profile settings.

Moreover, even if you switched from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code, you would have to use the file `.vscode/launch.json`.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I set route properties which be works for Azure App Service?

Comment: @ivan_spb_dev You most likely have an `appsettings.json` file for that :)

Comment: Yes, but it is only configuration storage. What is the command or option do I need set for correct work with ports and routes on Azure App hosting?

Comment: You'll probably be better off asking a new question after reading the documentation (if you still have doubts). I haven't worked on Azure services lately so I cannot help you too much. And this particular question (why launchsettings.json doesn't work) has been answered